# Вывести сумму прописью на Русском языке

Tags: php, yii2

В товарной накладной необходимо добавить сумму прописью.
Пробую так:

```
Yii::$app->language = 'ru-RU';
$stringTotalPrice = Yii::t('app', '{n, spellout}', [n => $totalPrice], 'ru-RU');
```

Пробовал и просто *ru* указывать, но сумма все равно выводится на инглише.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что этого "ru-RU" просто нет, по этому выводиться на "инглише"..

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 ru-RU точно есть, так как я еще использую метод вывода даты, и он (при этих установках) выводит на Русском.
Yii::$app->formatter->asDate(Carbon::now(), 'd MMMM') - выводит 26 июля

Comment: должно быть ``` ... ['n' => $totalPrice] ...```

Answer (score 0):

1. Убедитесь, что в файле `messages/ru-RU/app.php` есть константа `'{n, spellout}'` и что у неё есть перевод на русский язык.
2. Проверьте, что в конфигурационном файле `config/web.php` (если у вас шаблон приложения basic) в секции `components` подключён компонент [интернационализации](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-i18n):

```php
'i18n' => [
    'translations' => [
        'app*' => [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
            'fileMap' => [
                'app' => 'app.php',
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

3. Также у вас в массиве, передаваемом в третьем аргументе `Yii::t()`, у индекса отсутствуют апострофы, проверьте в коде.